# App stops unfortunately after clicking allow in run time permission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in some devices

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-runtime

i'am trying to set run time permission for MarshMallow+ devices.
When i do it asks for permission but when i click allow the app stops unfortunately.
If i open the app again it  works fine.
My code for run time permission:

```
int CurrentVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (CurrentVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!checkIfAlreadyhavePermission())
        {
            requestForSpecificPermission();
        }
    }

}
private boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
private void requestForSpecificPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {

                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    createall();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

createall:

```
 public void createall()
{

    String mediaLocation = "/VApp";
    String myfolder= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + mediaLocation;
    File mediaDir = new File(myfolder);

    if(!mediaDir.exists())
    {
        mediaDir.mkdir();
    }

    Toolbar toolBar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    adapter.addFragment(new RecentActivity(), "Recent");
    adapter.addFragment(new SavedActivity(), "Saved");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

this is my createall method but when i open app again after the app stopped this code works fine.

Comment: post error stacktrace

Comment: it shows no error in emulator,it stops when using in some real time devices @Yousaf

Comment: what does `createall();` method do?

Comment: it will create a directory,a tablayout in fragment.@Yousaf

Comment: post `createall()` method code

Comment: added createall() @yousaf

Comment: try running your app on android device with data cable still attached to your PC. Then try to grant permission, if app crashes, there will be error stacktrace in logcat. From error stacktrace you can identify the bug.

Comment: @Yousaf Thank you for your help,i checked the log file and found the answer and posted it below

Answer (score 0):

It is because:

```
    Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    adapter.addFragment(new RecentActivity(), "Recent");
    adapter.addFragment(new SavedActivity(), "Saved");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

the above code is written in `onCreate()` method

Just cut it and paste it in `onPostResume()` method
like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    adapter.addFragment(new RecentActivity(), "Recent");
    adapter.addFragment(new SavedActivity(), "Saved");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```